# NodeJs csv module - pause & resume

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv

I am using nodeJs csv module to parse a 10000 record big csv and at each record i.e., 
.on('record', func), I have to implement a time consuming logic. But node doesnt wait till I am done. How do I handle this? the docu talks about http://www.adaltas.com/projects/node-csv/ 
pause() and resume(). But where do I use it?

```
    var csv = require('csv');
    var fs = require('fs');
    csv()
    .from.stream(fs.createReadStream(__dirname+'/sample.in'))
    .to.path(__dirname+'/sample.out')
    .transform( function(row){
      row.unshift(row.pop());
      return row;
    })
    .on('record', function(row,index){
              //Time consuming logic goes here
    })
    .on('end', function(count){
      console.log('Number of lines: '+count);
    })
    .on('error', function(error){
      console.log(error.message);
    });
```

Comment: what is your node version? node prior to 10x has different implementation of pause and resume for readable streams.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally got this working. Thanks to node-csv developer

```
//Read through the csv file one row at a time
csv()
    .from(__dirname+'data.csv', { columns: true })
    .transform(function(row, index, next){
         setTimeout(function(){
         console.log(row);
         next()
         }, 3000); //replace setTimeout with any fn and call next() in the callback

    }, {parallel: 1})
    .on("end", function (count) {
      var finalcount = count;
      var logtext = 'SUMMARY: Total count: ' + finalcount + '\n' 
                    + 'Error count:' + errorcount  + "("+errorArray+")"
                    + '\n' + 'Success count:' + successcount;
      fs.appendFile(config.logfilename, '\n'+ logtext, function (err) {
        console.log(logtext);
      });  


      console.log("done", count);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I use fast-csv module in nodejs for large files.

```
require('colors');

const fs = require('fs');
const fastcsv = require('fast-csv');
const file = './path-to-your-file.csv';
const stream = fs.createReadStream(file);

const parser = fastcsv
  .parseStream(stream, { headers: true })
  .on('data', async function (item) {
    parser.pause();
    // any async func here
    await doSomethingWithDB(item);

    parser.resume();
  })
  .on('end', async (rowCount) => {
    console.log(`Parsed ${rowCount} rows`.green);
  });
```

Comment: Please explain how your code works and how it solves the issue from the question.

Comment: @AztecCodes Ever line of csv file parser will fire event of  *data* the the value of that will be available in data callback function as *item* in this example code than ```parser.pause()``` will stop the stream until you call the ```parser.resume()``` method.